# Does this sentence make sense? "I think it no use giving him money."

Tags: meaning

There are two sentences.

1. I think it no use giving him money.
2. I think it worth watching the movie.

Do the sentences above make sense?
I made these sentences myself.

Comment: You could say "I consider it a waste of time". But as mike says in his answer, with **think**  we say "I think it **is** a waste of time" in contemporary English.  Yet you can  say "I think it *unwise* to give him money."

Comment: *think it unwise* vs *think it is unwise*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=think+it+unwise%2Cthink+it+is+unwise&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthink%20it%20unwise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthink%20it%20is%20unwise%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I would argue that the first is correct (just idiomatic) but not the second.  The first can be rearranged to "I think it (giving him money) no use", with "no use" easily standing in for "unwise".  Whereas in the second, "I think it (watching the movie) worth" makes no sense, and "I think it (the movie) worth watching" is not an accurate transformation of the original sentence.

Comment: Yeah, I actually think these are technically correct, but they'd be interpreted as archaic at best, incorrect at worst. It's be better to include the "is" in some way, as mike mentions below.

Comment: The best answer is by Mike - add in "it's"
However "I think it no use **to give** him money"
is also technically correct, but sounds very old fashioned/posh

Comment: I wonder why you made these sentences up yourself? Why didn't you use a verb in the second part of the sentence?

Answer (score 24):

Both sentences are *correct* as they stand - however, it would be more natural to include an '*is*' (or more naturally when speaking, the contracted form *'s*), in the sentence. For example:

> - I think **it's** no use giving him money.
> - I think **it's** worth watching the movie.

With the second sentence (for me at least) it feels more natural to say:

> - I think the movie is worth watching.

Comment: they're both correct without the "is", as well. they're just a bit outdated and stuffy sounding.

Comment: @sgroves - I stand corrected - I didn't think about it from that perspective. If you have no objections, I'll update my answer with that information.

Comment: In the formal register that those sentences seem to aim for, "I think it no use **to give** him the money" would be the idiomatic phrasing for the first statement. The second doesn't scan well either; either "I think it **worthwhile to watch** the movie," or "I think it **of great worth** to watch the movie" would conform to the original structure and a high register while being much more natural.

Answer (score 10):

Both are grammatical, but rather literary: not many people would say them in ordinary speech today.

The basic structure is

> X thinks Y [to be] Z

('to be' is optional)
where Z is a description. "Think" here has the meaning of "judge" or "evaluate".

Your examples are related:

> X thinks it Z

where Z is a more complicated description, which involves an action and perhaps an actor.

More commonly, "think" takes a finite "that" clause:

> X thinks [that] Y is Z

The meaning of "think" here is a little wider: it can be judging or evaluating, but it can just express opinion or belief.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use this:

> - Giving him money is useless

or

> - There's no use giving him money

/

> - Watching this movie is pointless

or

> - There's no point watching this movie

Makes better sense to a native English person and has a more perfunctory tone.

Answer (score 0):

Stylistic note, you don't need to say, **"I think"**, it is implied when you make this kind of a statement that it is your opinion.

Lots of native speakers use **"I think"**, and there is nothing wrong with it from a grammar standpoint, but can weaken your argument and should generally be avoided.

If needed, you can always clarify later whether a statement is a fact or an opinion.

Comment: And since this is the English language forum, I should note that "Stylistic note" is shorthand for "On a stylistic note".

Comment: >Stylistic note, you don't need to say, "I think", it is implied when you make this kind of a statement that it is your opinion - woah, that is terrible advice

Comment: @Nye, is that a fact or is that what you think? heh.

Comment: @Octopus, lol, exactly. For the OP, see how much stronger Nye's statement is without using "I think"? Almost seems like it isn't just an opinion, doesn't it? :-)

Comment: If you want to emphasizes that something is your opinion, use "I think". It doesn't really weaken anything. It's dangerous making opinions appearing as facts. Example: "Everyone says we should do xxx. I think that ..." Stronger doesn't mean more right or true.